# Wagtail - made custom slug but page not serving from it

Tags: django, wagtail

I made a custom slug because the default slug does not meet my needs and already set the url_path with the new slug. But the page is still serving with the default slug.

I've already set the url_path with the following code:

```
def set_url_path(self, parent):
    super().set_url_path(self)
    if parent:
        self.url_path = parent.url_path + self.custom_slug + '/'
    return self.url_path
```

But when I publish the page, it still returns the page with the default slug value. I thought Wagtail serves the page on url_path. What other methods or variables do I have to override for the page to be served on my custom slug?

Comment: Why do you have the `custom_slug` field? Can't you just write Page.slug on clean or save?

Comment: @allcaps The value I wanna have does not get pass SlugField's default validation so I decided to make my own custom slug with my own validation.

Answer (score 1):

You can not switch to some other field then slug. The slug field is used all over Wagtail to lookup url's, queries and serve the correct page.

You can programatically set the slug value to something else. The Page.slug definition is:

```
slug = models.SlugField(
    verbose_name=_('slug'),
    allow_unicode=True,
    max_length=255,
    help_text=_("The name of the page as it will appear in URLs e.g 
                 http://example.com/blog/[my-slug]/")
)
```

The field accepts unicode chars.

You should override `Page._get_autogenerated_slug`, `Page.full_clean` and `Page.clean`. Change how slug is handled and adopt to your wishes.

Note you can use some other field eg `my_custom_slug` as an input and use this value in your custom methods. Eg: `self.my_custom_slug`. However, the final result has to be stored in the slug field.

You can remove the slug field from the content panels to remove it from the admin user interface.

Finally, the slug has to comply with https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1738